# Command pattern in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement a command line server application in Rust.
I'd like to have a list (or hash table) of commands that I can iterate over for printing usage and looking up/executing commands.

My problem is that each `Command` needs mutable references to the thing the command uses to execute (such as inserting a user into a database or something).  The borrow checker obviously doesn't like passing multiple mutable references around.  Is there a way to do this?  I started by having the `execute` method take in a reference to the things it needed but then I need a separate list for commands that need different things which sounds like it would get unwieldy.

Here's an example of the problem:

```
struct SomeStruct {
    pub some_field: String,
}

impl SomeStruct {
    pub fn new(field: String) -> SomeStruct {
        let some_struct = SomeStruct {
            some_field: field,
        };
        return some_struct;
    }

    pub fn change_field(&mut self) {
        self.some_field = "Something else".to_string();
    }
}

struct SomeCommand<'a> {
    pub some_struct: &'a mut SomeStruct,
}

impl<'a> SomeCommand<'a> {
    pub fn new(the_struct: &'a mut SomeStruct) -> SomeCommand {
        let some_command = SomeCommand {
            some_struct: the_struct,
        };
        return some_command;
    }

    pub fn execute(&mut self) {
        self.some_struct.change_field();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut some_struct = SomeStruct::new("hey".to_string());
    let some_command1 = SomeCommand::new(&mut some_struct);

    // Compiler complains because I'm making another mutable binding to some_struct
    let some_command2 = SomeCommand::new(&mut some_struct);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to do the same in Rust, following examples in book Design Patterns. The problem here is that we need to maintain the generic interface of the `Command` trait, which means we should not design the trait such that it takes specific objects of certain types. The only solution we are left with is to store a mutable reference to the object itself within the concrete instance of object that implements `Command` trait. However, if we use `&'a mut ...`, Rust compiler will not like multiple mutable references to a single object, which means we can only ever have one `Command` instance for any given object we want to execute the command on, and we can only call execute once.

This can be achieved by using `RefCell` or `Arc<Mutex<>>`. I have implemented both and they both work very well. The difference is that `RefCell` is not thread-safe, so you cannot share the same `Command` object across threads if you choose to implement it in this way; whereas `Arc<Mutex<>>` is thread-safe.

Below is my implementation:

```rust
trait Command {
    fn execute(&mut self);            // Execute command.
    fn is_reversible(&self) -> bool;  // Undoable operation?
    fn unexecute(&mut self);          // Undo command.
}

// ------ Using RefCell ------

struct ChangeFontSizeCommand<'a> {
    text: &'a RefCell<dyn Text>,
    old_size: Option<usize>,
    new_size: usize
}

impl<'a> Command for ChangeFontSizeCommand<'a> {
    // Implementation... (many calls to .borrow() and .borrow_mut())
}

impl<'a> ChangeFontSizeCommand<'a> {
    pub fn new(text: &'a RefCell<dyn Text>, new_size: usize) -> Self {
        // Implementation...
    }
}

// ------ Using Arc and Mutex ------

struct ChangeFontColorCommand {
    text: Arc<Mutex<dyn Text>>,
    old_color: Option<Color>,
    new_color: Color
}

impl Command for ChangeFontColorCommand {
    // Implementation... (many calls to .lock().unwrap())
}

impl ChangeFontColorCommand {
    pub fn new(text: Arc<Mutex<dyn Text>>, new_color: Color) -> Self {
        // Implementation...
    }
}
```

Notice that in both examples, instance of `RefCell` or `Arc<Mutex<>>` has to be created *outside* of object initializer, we cannot pass in a mutable reference and create them inside of the command implementation struct, that would violate Rust's borrow checker rules.

Comment: Wow thank you I had forgotten about this question. This is exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think passing the mutable reference as a parameter of `execute()` instead of storing it within `SomeCommand` is the way to go. Don't keep references living longer than they need to live.

But this is a fairly broad question: I can think of a dozen possible solutions -- it's hard to tell what's best in your case, since your example is pretty generic. Maybe we could be more specific after you told us a little more (maybe a small subset of features you want to implement).

Just looking at the title of your post: [`docopt`](https://github.com/docopt/docopt.rs) is used by many Rust project -- AFAIK even `cargo` uses it. However, I suspect it doesn't help you with your main design problem.

---

Besides: in your `new` methods you can delete some code thanks to implicit returns. This:

```
pub fn new(field: String) -> SomeStruct {
    let some_struct = SomeStruct {
        some_field: field,
    };
    return some_struct;
}
```

... becomes this:

```
pub fn new(field: String) -> SomeStruct {
    SomeStruct {
        some_field: field,
    }
}
```

Comment: Well thanks I appreciate the response.  I basically have a few different objects that are needed depending on the command and didn't want to have separate lists for each command that has different dependencies.  Still a rust noob, trying to make it C++ heh.

Comment: So your program `foo` would be callable as `foo add <user>`, `foo delete <user>`, `foo add <group>` and `foo delete <group>` or something like that? Then you would have 4 `Command` objects. I don't see how you would be able to generically treat all commands at all. You have to have a few different cases in which you execute different code. For example: fetching information about the user and group are two different operations. In short: I don't think the design you're thinking of would help. Maybe you could post the your code on CodeReview-Stackexchange...

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt: CodeReview is for working code (ie, code that compiles, runs and gives the expected result).